# How do I open a mongodb connection before all tests running, and close it after all tests running, in mocha?

Tags: unit-testing, mongodb, mocha.js

I'm using [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) to write unit tests for a nodejs+mongodb web application. There are many test files there need to operate mongodb.

So I want to open a connection before all tests running, and close it after all tests, but I don't know how to do it.

At present, I create a file `dbtest_global.js`, which has such code:

```
before(function(done) {
    console.log('before all');
    global.connection = openMongoDB();
    done();
});

after(function(done) {
   global.connection.close(done);
});
```

Then in other tests, I use `require('./dbtest_global')` to require it.

But I found when running `mocha`, the `before` method will be invoked multi-times, which makes the `global.connection` changed many times.

I wonder is there any way to let the `before` and `after` methods only be invoked exactly one time when running `mocha`?

Comment: Maybe the behaviour has changed since you asked this question, but if that is the entirety of `dbtest_global.js`, that `before` should only be executed only once. Basically the same as the solution answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16321613/227578, and from a quick test, seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a plain global condition variable, that ensures that the before function immediately returns, if the variable has already been set?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out mongodb helpers for mocha - https://github.com/arunoda/mocha-mongo

It creates db connection for you and clean the collections before the test.