# Cleaning out test database before running tests

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, sequelize.js

What is the best way to clean out a database before running a test suite (is there a npm library or recommended method of doing this).

I know about the before() function.

I'm using node/express, mocha and sequelize.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `before` function is about as good as you will do for cleaning out your database. If you only need to clean out the database once i.e. before you run all your tests, you can have a global `before` function in a separate file

### globalBefore.js

```
before(function(done) {
   // remove database data here
   done()
})
```

### single-test-1.js

```
require('./globalBefore')
// actual test 1 here
```

### single-test-2.js

```
require('./globalBefore')
// actual test 2 here
```

Note that the globalBefore will only run once even though it has been required twice

## Testing Principles

Try to limit the use of external dependecies such as databases in your tests. The less external dependencies the easier the testing. You want to be able to run all your unit tests in parallel and a shared resource such as a database makes this difficult.

Take a look at this Google Tech talk about writing testable javascript
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjqKQ8ezwKQ

Also take look at the [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) module. It works quite well for stubbing out functions.

Answer (score 19):

I usually do it like this (say for a `User` model):

```
describe('User', function() {
  before(function(done) {
    User.sync({ force : true }) // drops table and re-creates it
      .success(function() {
        done(null);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
        done(error);
      });
  });

  describe('#create', function() {
    ...
  });
});
```

There's also `sequelize.sync({force: true})` which will drop and re-create *all* tables (`.sync()` is described [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/schema/)).

Comment: Any modern approach to this?

Comment: @coler-j Sequelize uses promises nowadays, so `before(() => User.sync({ force : true }))` should work as well now (if that's what you mean by "modern approach" :D)

Comment: I was just wondering if there were any native ways to automatically wrap test cases in transactions that were built in, as it seems like a very common requirement.

Comment: @coler-j `before` (and also `beforeEach`) can be applied to every set of tests, so you can start a transaction before each test (of set of tests) and either commit or roll back afterwards (using `after` or `afterEach`). Mocha as a test runner doesn't deal with databases at all, so it's not a built-in feature.

Comment: Ok, I was just seeing in issues (like https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4189 and https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3888 and https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4823) this that the event loop is exited when a test is completed and that it is not possible to roll back a transaction in the afterEach due to something I don't understand with CLS

Comment: @coler-j ah sorry, I guess I thought it was going to be easy :/ the issues you're referring to are pretty old, but I guess they still apply? Not sure if I like Sequelize to be using something like CLS, because (apparently) it can cause unexpected issues with other frameworks (Mocha in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your test file . This would undo all the migrations and create new tables while adding the seeded data to let you do testing on the seeded data.

```
const SCRIPT_TO_TRUNCATE_AND_SEED_DATABASE = 'cd apps/backend && npx sequelize-cli db:migrate:undo:all && npx sequelize-cli db:migrate && cd ../.. && npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all'
test(
    'TRUNCATE_AND_SEED_DATABASE',
    done => {
      exec(SCRIPT_TO_TRUNCATE_AND_SEED_DATABASE, (err, out) => {
        try {
          console.log(out);
          expect(err).toBe(null);
          done();
        } catch (e) {
          done(e);
        }
      });
    },
    TIME_CONSTANT.ONE_MINUTE,
  );
```

Answer (score -3):

I made this lib to clean and import fixtures for your test.

This way, you can import fixtures, test and then clean your database.

Take a look at the following:

```
before(function (done) {
   prepare.start(['people'], function () {
      done();
   });
});

after(function () {
   prepare.end();
});
```

https://github.com/diogolmenezes/test_prepare

Comment: The library you suggested is for MongoDB but the question states sequelize.