# How do you instruct mocha/nodejs to wait till all db operations are over

Tags: node.js, redis, mocha.js

I'm trying to test if some of my db operations are executed properly. The flow is as follows (I'm using mocha for testing)

1. Call code which loops through data and saves it to redis
2. Get data from redis (in my testcase)  to see if it saves the right data.

I'm noticing that the get data from db gets executed much before anything is saved. I was looking at the done() option in mocha, however that seems to work only if data is saved through mocha (setup etc).

So how do I instruct mocha to wait for all db to be saved before trying to retrieve from db?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

dankohn is correct. Here's what you need to do, a bit more fleshed out:

```
describe('Your test', function () {
    before(function (done) {
        Your.redis.db.call.here(your, parameters, function (err) {
            ...you may want to check for errors first...
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should do what you wanted...', function (done) {
        ...your test case...
        done();
    });
});
```

Your redis call most likely provides a callback function as a parameter. That callback function is executed when the redis call is completed. Within that callback function, call `done()`. The data you wrote will be there throughout your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write a before function with the parameter done in mocha to load the data into the database. As a callback for when your data is loaded, call done(). Now, all your data will load before your first test.

Comment: I wasn't talking about loading data. This is testing a business function which does database operations and then testing to see if those database operations were done correctly.

Comment: Yes, I'm giving you directions on how to use the before function in mocha to setup your data before running tests. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16321613/1935918